# Why doesn't this if :focus statement work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  if($("select").is(":focus")){
    $(document).click(function(){
      $("select").blur()
      console.log('lala')
    })
  }

  $(document).click(function(){
    console.log($('select').is(':focus'))
  })

})
```

So what happens here is that I've binded a click on anywhere to let me know if `select` is opened. And if it is, it should close and output `lala` in console. This doesn't happen, but the other click event does let me know if it is or is not opened.

So the bug is on the first part of the code, but where?

Comment: what is "select"? I guess you haven't used any selectors here "#" or '.'.

Comment: @Ajai `select` is `<select>` tag

Comment: So is `$("select").is(":focus")` true when that code is evaluated?

Comment: @zerkms it's true if it is opened and false when it's not.

Comment: @Ajai Surely the select element https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: @Xeen is it "opened" when a page is loaded? If not - when you expect it to run?

Comment: @zerkms it's not opened on page load, but I do expect it to run when it's opened.

Comment: @Xeen it's not opened on page load, so the `click` event handler is not bound (and never will be)

Comment: @Xeen The point here is that the if condition is checked exactly once, at document ready. If it is false the click event is never registered.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should write like this:

```
$(document).click(function(){
   if($("select").is(":focus")) {
     $("select").blur();
     console.log('lala')
   }
});
```

It will work.

Comment: Thanks, but no, I need it to close when a click is performed.

Comment: @Xeen if you do want to close it - why there is no corresponding code in your example?

Comment: @Juhana yes, my bad :) But this doesn't work because it instantly closes the select drop down once it's opened.

Comment: @Xeen so don't close it instantly. JS works exactly like you ask it to.

Comment: @zerkms no, but the point is that I want it to close whenever there's a click of a button. With this approach, it closes whenever I release the button

Comment: @Xeen so add a handler that runs when you click on a button. It seriously is not clear what actual problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

You've binded click event on document ready when select is focused. you should use this

```
$(document).click(function(){
    if($("select").is(":focus")){
        $("select").blur()
        console.log('lala')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assign ID** to select tag:

```
<select id="selectGender"></select>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
  if($("#selectGender").is(":focus")){
    $(document).click(function(){
      $("#selectGender").blur()
      console.log('lala');
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will quote the api text, becuase i thing you definetely should precede a tag selector.

> As with other pseudo-class selectors (those that begin with a ":"), it is recommended to precede :focus with a tag name or some other selector

https://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/